# How to get each set value of class property

Tags: c#, async-await

my question is how to get each set value of the class, in the code below?

```
class Reservation
   {
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
       public int no_date { get; set; }
       public DateTime check_in { get; set; }
       public DateTime check_out { get; set; }
       public List<string> type_no { get; set; }
       public decimal balance { get; set; }
       public decimal payed { get; set; }
       public decimal vat { get; set; }
       public decimal sub_total { get; set; }
   }
```

**Set the value of the class**

```
Reservation roomReservation = new Reservation()
 {
   id = checkInID,//CheckInId
   type = "Room",
   no_date = Convert.ToInt32(txtNoDays.Text.Trim()),
   check_in = dtpDateIn.Value,
   check_out = dtpDateOut.Value,
   type_no = roomNo,
   balance = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBalance.Text.Trim()),
   payed = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPayed.Text.Trim()),
   vat = Convert.ToDecimal(txtVatAmount.Text.Trim()),
   sub_total = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubTotal.Text.Trim()),
  };
await sendToWeb.createReservation(roomReservation, roomNoDT);
```

**My question is how to get each set values?**

```
public static async Task createReservation(object forBothReservation, DataTable eachRoomNoOrHallName)
    {
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(forBothReservation);
     StringContent data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

// my question how can i get each set value of (object)forBothReservation ?
    }
```

**What I have tried**
like

```
forBothReservation[0].type, forBothReservation[0].no_date
```

Comment: If you know the type is a `Reservation`, why does your method take `object`? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ok my bad, I changed, how can i get value ?

Comment: Well, `forBothReservation` isn't an array, so you can't index it (i.e. `[0]` won't work). I would expect `forBothReservation.type` to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Reservation
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int no_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime check_in { get; set; }
        public DateTime check_out { get; set; }
        public List<string> type_no { get; set; }
        public decimal balance { get; set; }
        public decimal payed { get; set; }
        public decimal vat { get; set; }
        public decimal sub_total { get; set; }

        public string ToJson()
        {
            var jsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
            jsonSetting.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, jsonSetting);
        }

    }    

    public static async Task createReservation(Reservation forBothReservation, DataTable eachRoomNoOrHallName)
    {
        var id = forBothReservation.id;
        var no_date = forBothReservation.no_date;
    }
```